# Android onScale onTouchEvent

Tags: android, zooming, touch-event

in my app user can do something by moving a finger on the screen and an other action when zooming on the screen.
My app listen scale event and on touch event.

My problem is when user zooms, the two finger never touch the screen at the same time so the first finger who touch the screen call on touch event instead of on Scale (when the 2nd finger came it call onScale but a wrong function has been called before).

I have the same problem after the zoom when user get his finger off.

someone know what to do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Touch events are too low level in this case as you have already experienced. Use the `ScaleGestureDetector` that handles it for you. A simple example taken from the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html) can be something like

```
public MyCustomView(Context mContext){
    ...
    // View code goes here
    ...
    scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    if(!scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
       // detect the move event here
    }
    return true;
}
```

The same detector pattern should be used for other more complex events like dragging.

Comment: i use scalegesturedetector to detect the zoom but in my onTouchEvent function i had to detect movement too. When a zoom is detect, it detects movements too. it's my problem.

Comment: i had to translate my view when i move a finger and zoom when i pinch. my problem is when a pinch is done, system keep last finger position as a movement event

Comment: @Nos `scaleDetector.onTouchEvent()` returns a boolean that indicates whether the event was handled. That's how you can mutally exclude both detections.